# Jekyll use the JS variable for IF condition

Tags: javascript, jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a website right now in Jekyll.

I want to make a page where the content will change according to `GET variables`.

I've got different links as follow :

```
<a href="/oneBenchmark?logic=k&problem=cnf"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>

<a href="/oneBenchmark?logic=t&problem=cnf"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
```

I've got also the page `oneBenchmark.html` as follow :

```
---
layout: page
permalink: /oneBenchmark/
---

<script>
    var splitUrl = function() {

        var vars = [], hash;
        var url = document.URL.split('?')[0];
        var p = document.URL.split('?')[1];
            if(p != undefined){
                p = p.split('&');
                for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
                    hash = p[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[1]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
            }
            vars['url'] = url;
            return vars;
    };

    var url = splitUrl();

    var logic   = url[0];
    var problem = url[1];

    console.log(logic);
    console.log(problem);
</script>

{% for bench in site.benchmarks %}
    {% if bench.logic == logic %} 
        {% if bench.problem == problem %}           
            {{bench.content}}
        {% endif %}         
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The little Javascript code gives me 2 variables "logic" and "problem" which contain the value in the URL.

I would like in the IF of Jekyll, to use my JavaScript variables in order to check which content I should display.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to call my JavaScript variables in this IF nor how to achieve this goal differently :/

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jekyll is a **static** site generator and you want to use it to generate a **dynamic** content. You are missing the purpose of using Jekyll. I think it's a bad idea with **emphases on bad!**

Jekyll creates the content up a head this mean that once you get to your page it's already created because it's a static generator and it can't create content on the fly!.

Even if you filter your way using `javaScript` you have no way of asking Jekyll for a specific data and re-generate that data as a new page content. As I see it your only option is to generate the whole data to the page as content using Jekyll and then use `javaScript` to hide/show the relevant content.

As I previously said I don't recommend using Jekyll that way and it won't scale on the long run. This also lead's to a very bad user experience:

- **Scenario 1:** User wait's for the page to render itself while seeing content appears and disappears from the screen - not knowing when the page is finally ready with the correct content.
- **Scenario 2:** hide the entire content and present a message to the user `"please wait content loading..."`  User may end up waiting for a long time for the process to end and then get the correct page content).

I think you need to re-check all of your site requirements and choose the correct technology to implement it. Maybe Jekyll isn't exactly what you need.

[jekyll](/questions/tagged/jekyll) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [liquid](/questions/tagged/liquid)

Answer (score 3):

The first important thing
**The liquid syntax (e.g. {% for %}) is generated by Jekyll **before** users see the page so there is no way to use the variable passed by the user inside it.**

But don't give up soon! There still might be a way while you use your creativity.
Essentially  when you want to modify the page based on user actions you may use:

1. parameters passed in URL;
2. JavaScript.

For example, I have created a webpage with a small database that allows users to search items in it (by name, for example). And this was a static page!) I used {% for %} loop to list empty div with id for all the items from the database from the beginning. And in JavaScript based on the URL I got from the user I would modify filtered divs to show content.

My html:

```
---
layout: default
---

{% for item in site.data.items %}
    <div id="{{ item.id }}"></div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
function addFilteredElements() {
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var name = url.searchParams.get("name");

    {% for item in site.data.items %}
        if (name == null || {{ item.name }} == name) {
            element = document.getElementById('{{ item.id }}');
            element.innerHTML = '{{ item.name }}, {{note.semester}}';
            console.log('yay!');
        }
    {% endfor %}
}
</script>
<body onload="addFilteredElements();">
```

items.yml

```
- name: exampleName0
  id: exampleId0

- name: exampleName1
  id: exampleId1
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'm happy to give you your first up-vote in stack overflow :)

Comment: @wineunuuchs2unix ahah) thanks))) I’m glad that you are “my first”